# Polymorphism and Dynamic Binding

Tags: java, polymorphism, dynamic-binding

Assuming that we have three classes as below

```
public class Woo extends Zoo {
    public String one() {
        return "wee" + this.two();
    }
    public String extra() {
        return "eek" + this.one();
    }
}

public class Zoo {
    public String one() {
        return "zee";
    }
public String two() {
        return "zow";
    }
}

public class Yoo extends Woo {
    public String two() {
        return "yow";
    }
}
```

And assuming we made the variable declaration of:

```
 Zoo z = new Yoo();
```

What would the output of

```
System.out.println(z.one() + " " + z.two() + " " + z.extra());
```

be?

My compiler won't let me compile saying that

> no method in Zoo has extra

But I thought that since the actual type of `z` is class `Yoo`, and since `Yoo` inherits all the methods from `Zoo` and `Woo` class, `z.extra()` would work....?

Comment: At compile time, z is of type Zoo, which does not have the 'extra' method..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though you assign z a value of type `Yoo`, it is still a `Zoo` object. Therefore, Java has no way of knowing about the `extra` method. You have to cast z to `Yoo` or `Woo` to access that method. For example:

```
Zoo zoo = new Yoo();
Yoo yoo = (Yoo) zoo;

yoo.extra();
```

Or...

```
Zoo zoo = new Yoo();
Woo wyoo = (Woo) zoo;

wyoo.extra();
```

You could even do

```
Zoo zoo = new Yoo();
((Woo) zoo).extra();
```

and leave out a line.

---

In addition, say you were to override `extra` in your `Yoo` class. Calling `wyoo.extra()` from the second example above would call the overridden version from the `Yoo` class, because Java doesn't care about the contents of a method, just that the method is guaranteed to exist.

Answer (score 0):

If you fix the type of `z` to be `Yoo` or cast to `Yoo` before calling `extra` (as the other answers describe pretty well), you will be able to compile and the output should be

```
weeyow yow eekzee
```